# Cyclic Quadrilateral and area condition

Tags: geometry, contest-math, area

Let $ABCD$ a convex quadrilateral with $AC$ $\perp$ $BD$ , the point $P$ is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of $AB$ and $CD$ ($P$ is inside $ABCD$).Show that $ABCD$ is cyclic if and only if $\triangle ABP$ and $\triangle CDP$ have the same area.

I tried a lot this problem but I couldn't finish it. I only Showed that if $ABCD$ is cyclic then $\triangle ABP $ and $\triangle CDP$ have the same area. Here is my solution:
As P is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of $AB$ and $CD$ and the fact that $ABCD$ is cyclic implies $P$ is the circuncenter of $ABCD$, this implies $AP$=$BP$=$CP$=$DP$. As $AC$ $\perp$ $BD$ implies that $\angle APB$ + $\angle CPD$ = 180. This implies $\triangle ABP$ and $\triangle CDP$ have the same area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider other way round. Let $[ABP] = [CDP]$.

Now first notice by construction of point $P$ we have $PA = PB$ and $PC = PD$
Now let us drop perpendiculars $PH$, $PI$ from $P$ to $BD$ and $AC$ respectively  as shown in figure below

now we have
$[PAB] = [AEB] + [BEP] - [AEP] = \frac{BE\cdot AE +  BE \cdot PH - AE \cdot PI}{2}$

and

$[PDC] = [EDC] + [PEC] - [EDP] = \frac{EC \cdot DE  + EC \cdot PI - DE \cdot PH}{2}$

now also notice that $PHEI$ is a rectangle (by construction of $PH, PI$ and diagonals are perpendicular), hence $PH = EI $  and $HE=PI$ now equate above equations and write it using $BH, DH, AI$ and $CI$

you will get $BH \cdot AI = CI \cdot DH$

now let on contrary, WLOGI $PA > PD $ but that means $PA > PC$ for $PD = PC$ hence consider the triangle $PAC$ we have $AI$ as altitude so $PA > PD \Rightarrow AI > CI$
similarly $PA > PD \Rightarrow PB > PD \Rightarrow BH > DH$ combining we get $BH \cdot AI > DH \cdot CI$ which is contradiction
[image: diagram]